# Why debounce() with toList() doen't working in RxAndroid?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

While I'm using `debounce()` ,then fetch data from backend and the data 
I want to convert to another data and lastly use `toList()`.
when I'm using `toList()` nothing happens no any log not in subscribe and error ,without `toList()` it works and `subscribe()` method enters as much as I have list of books, I tested the second part of code it without `debounce()` just `getItems()` and using `toList()` it works. 
Below is my code the first part with `debounce()` and `itList()` which is not working and the second  with `toList()` which works

```
public Flowable<List<Book>> getItems(String query) {}

textChangeSubscriber
            .debounce(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .switchMap(s -> getItems(s).toObservable())
            .flatMapIterable(items -> items)
            .map(Book::convert)
            .toList()
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(books -> {
                Log.i("test", "" + books.toString());
            }, error -> {
                Log.i("test", "" + error);
            });


   getItems(query).flatMapIterable(items -> items)
            .map(Book::convert)
            .toList()
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(books -> {
                Log.i("test", "" + "" + books.toString());
            }, error -> {
                Log.i("test", "" + error);
            });
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`toList` requires the sequence to terminate which doesn't happen on the outer stream that responds to text events. You should move the processing of the books into the `switchMap`:

```
textChangeSubscriber
        .map(CharSequence::toString) // <-- text components emit mutable CharSequence
        .debounce(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .switchMap(s -> 
              getItems(s)
              .flatMapIterable(items -> items)
              .map(Book::convert)
              .toList()
              .toFlowable() // or toObservable(), depending on textChangeSubscriber
        )
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(books -> {
            Log.i("test", "" + books.toString());
        }, error -> {
            Log.i("test", "" + error);
        });
```