# Two sequence of Flowable don't reach the to toList()

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android, rx-java2

I have Flowable object. I’m doing following actions 
`Flowable -> flatmapIterable()->map()->toList()` it works perfect
while when I use the same chain of actions I have, but before
Flowable I have another Flowable which I flatmap and get another Flowable
like

```
Flowable->flatmap(receive Flowable the above flowable) ->flatmapIterable()->map()->toList()
```

it reaches the toList() method and it stops there I don’t receive after toList() part where I subscribe()

Answer (score 3):

`Flowable.toList()` will only emit something after the `onComplete` notification from the source arrives. In your example this means the original flowable and all the flowables created in the `flatMap` have completed.

If nothing is emitted that must mean one of those Flowables has not yet ended or never ends.

Comment: thanks for answer, when I put. log in map() it Logs 11 times because my list items are 11, how can I understand that one of them is not emitted ? and what the solution ,if I want to receive list whatever is emitted?

Comment: @A.A.I.A Check this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43684734/why-debounce-with-tolist-doent-working-in-rxandroid/43685406#43685406